# Increment in month value in Date class in Java

Tags: java, date

So, I'm typing a very simple program to accept the date from the user and print it back to them.
On my first attempt, i saw that the year gets incremented by 1900. What exactly is the reason?
I also see that the month value is being incremented by one. Here is the program block

```
Date dateInput = new Date(114,2,20,13,18,48); //2014-1900 = 114
System.out.println("Date Entered by You : ");
System.out.println(dateInput);
```

The output for this is

```
Date Entered by You : 
Thu Mar 20 13:18:48 IST 2014
```

I entered the month value as 2, but it it printing at as March. What could be the problem?
And why is the Date class preprogrammed to add a 1900 to the entered year?

Comment: Why don't you read the javadoc of the Date class. It has all the explanations you need. And it will tell you what to use instead of this deprecated constructor.

Comment: I'd like to have a fairly robust conversation with the Java team who decided to zero-base the months. It's at odds with ISO month counting for starters. The confusion is not your fault IMO, so +1.

Comment: everyone knows that month are indexed with 0-11 but it would be interesting to know if anyone here can answer why we shouldnt creat a date before 1900. why didnt the api want that?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah. Thats what confused me. The date wasnt zero based, so i assumed the months wouldn't be zero based too. Shouldve checked the Date API though.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) API

> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is
>   February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

---

> I entered the month value as 2, but it it printing at as March. What
>   could be the problem?

So as per api, in your case, it's March.

> On my first attempt, i saw that the year gets incremented by 1900.
>   What exactly is the reason?

You have used depreciated [`Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec)` Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), and it's says

> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(**year + 1900**, month,
>   date, hrs, min, sec) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date,
>   hrs, min, sec). Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it
>   represents the instant at the start of the second specified by the
>   year, month, date, hrs, min, and sec arguments, in the local time
>   zone.

---

*And, It's just part of the horrendous mess which is the Java date/time API. Month starts with zero, but, day starts with 1. In [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), the new [`java.time.*` package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (defined by [JSR-310](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#jsr310) and inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)) [fixes this problem](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) and more.*

Comment: Oh wow. I didnt know that! Thanks a lot! What about the year?

Comment: @woodhead92: re-read the answer. It starts with "Check the Date API". Click the link, and you'll have the answer.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran What about the -1900 in the year? What is the reason for it?

Answer (score 3):

The month index start from 0-January 1 febuary ans so on 11 for december

Answer (score 1):

This is Date source code:

```
public Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec) {
    int y = year + 1900;
    // month is 0-based. So we have to normalize month to support Long.MAX_VALUE.
    if (month >= 12) {
        y += month / 12;
        month %= 12;
    } else if (month < 0) {
        y += CalendarUtils.floorDivide(month, 12);
        month = CalendarUtils.mod(month, 12);
    }
    BaseCalendar cal = getCalendarSystem(y);
    cdate = (BaseCalendar.Date) cal.newCalendarDate(TimeZone.getDefaultRef());
    cdate.setNormalizedDate(y, month + 1, date).setTimeOfDay(hrs, min, sec, 0);
    getTimeImpl();
    cdate = null;
}
```

Month start with Jan-0, Feb-1...

In above source code you can find why you have to `subtract 1900`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 2014 , 2 , 20 , 13 , 18 , 48 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
```

> 2014-02-20T13:18:48+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

## java.time

Use modern *java.time* classes that have sane numbering. Avoid the troublesome poorly-designed old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

No crazy numbering in *java.time*:

- `2014` means the year 2014. No funky math with 1900.
- `2` means February, 1-12 for January-December.
- `1` means Monday, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

So, if you want early afternoon on March 20, 2014 in India time zone:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2014 , 2 , 20 , 13 , 18 , 48 , 0 , z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2014-02-20T13:18:48+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Or build in pieces.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , 2 , 20 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 13 , 18 , 48 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.FEBRUARY , 20 ) ;
```

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).